# Subgroups of $ \mathbb{Z}^n $

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I'm having a difficulty proving the following:

Let $ H \leq \mathbb{Z}^n $ be a subgroup. Prove that $ H \simeq \mathbb{Z}^k $, $ k \leq n $.

Moreover, prove that if

$ H = \{(c_1, \dots, c_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^n; a_1c_1 + \dots + a_1c_1 = 0 \} $,

where $ (a_1, \dots, a_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^n \setminus \{0\} $

then $ k=n-1 $

So what I've got, I can prove that every subgroup of $ \mathbb{Z^n} $ is finitely generated (and abelian, of course), therefore

$ H \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{q_1} \times \dots \times \mathbb{Z}_{q_r} \times \mathbb{Z}^k $ for some $ k \in \mathbb{N} $ and $ q_1, \dots, q_r $ - powers of primes. Maybe now I can say that no element of $ \mathbb{Z^n} $ except $ 0 $ is of finite order, but elements such at $ (1, 0, \dots, 0) $ are, which means that $ \mathbb{Z}_{q_i} \simeq \{0\} $. Knowing that $ k \leq n $ is rather obvious.

The other part is what gets me. I can see I'm gonna need using the first one, but I'm stuck there

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have written $a_1c_1+\cdots+a_1c_1=0$. Perhaps you can edit it, so it says what you meant to say. Anyway, all you need is $n-1$ independent generators, which you can get by letting all the coefficients except the 1st and the $j$th be zero, $j=2,\dots,n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** There is an exact sequence $0 \to H \to \mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$. In general, if $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ is an exact sequence of abelian groups, then $\mathrm{rank}(B) = \mathrm{rank}(A) + \mathrm{rank}(C)$.

Comment: Well, so should it go this way:

Let $ \phi : H \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^n; \phi(c_1, \dots, c_n) = (c_1, \dots, c_n) $ and $ \psi: \mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}; \psi(c_1, \dots, c_n) = c_1a_1 + \dots + c_1a_n $. Of course the image of $ \phi $ is the kernel of $ \psi $ and by the lemma you mentioned $ \mathrm{rank}(H) = n-1 $.

Could you please show me where to find a proof of this lemma?

Comment: Yes, but note that $\psi$ is not surjective, still the image is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ (why?). The Lemma is easy to prove when you know tensor products; in fact this reduces the statement to $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, where it is well-known from linear algebra. Here you can also do the following: If $0\to\mathbb{Z}^r\to\mathbb{Z}^n\to\mathbb{Z}^m\to 0$ is exact, then it splits (why?), hence $\mathbb{Z}^n \cong\mathbb{Z}^{r+m}$. Now there are plenty of ways proving that this implies $n=r+m$, but since you have used the structure theorem for abelian groups, you probably already know this.

Comment: Yeah, of course. I'm not familiar with tensor products yet, but thank you. Of course every non-zero subgroup of $ \mathbb{Z} $ is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{Z} $. Thank you